# How do I handle all errors on my server, so that it never crashes?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, try-catch

Let's say I have this server route (using expressjs):

```
app.get('/cards', function(req, res) {
    anUndefinedVariable // Server doesn't crash
    dbClient.query('select * from cards', function(err, result) {
        anUndefinedVariable // Server crashes
        res.send(result.rows)
    });
});
```

When I simply reference an undefined variable at the root of the `/cards` route callback, the server doesn't crash, but if I reference it in the nested callback it crashes.

Is it because Express is catching the error when it's at the root level? Why doesn't it also catch the errors in the nested functions?

I tried catching the error like this myself:

```
app.get('/cards', function(req, res) {
    try {
        dbClient.query('select * from cards', function(err, result) {
            anUndefinedVariable
            res.send(result.rows)
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('...')
    }
});
```

But it never enters the catch block. Maybe this is the reason Express isn't able to catch the error. Is it because that, in order to be able to catch an error, you need to do it on the function that actually calls the callback? E.g. `try {functionThatCallsTheQueryCallback() } catch(e) {...}`? I don't think so, as `query` certainly calls the callback indirectly at a certain point.

How would I go about catching all errors so that my server never crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try...catch` only catches errors that occur in synchronous operations. It won't catch errors that occur in callbacks to async operations, like you have in your second example above.

As for the first example, express handles errors that are thrown synchronously and sends a 500 response to the client.

You can look into [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) for handling errors across async operations. But be aware that they are pending deprecation. It's worth reading through the warnings in the docs about why they're being deprecated.

Comment: But isn't the code inside `app.get('/cards', function(req, res) { ... })` asynchronous? Or is it only asnychronous for us, but not for Express, since Express calls the callback?

Comment: That's right. Express invokes your route handler in response to an async event, but it invokes it synchronously and so can catch any synchronous errors. I believe this is the source: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L86

Answer (score 0):

It can done in node, although generally not recommended, by letting node to handle the uncaughtException event,
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(`Caught exception: ${err}`);
});
```

Another more preferable approach would be just let it crush, and have it restarted automatically afterward. There are some tools available for this, such as nodemon, pm2, forever...